# magento-cron job module not working

Tags: magento, cron

There are plenty of tutorials out there for setting up cron, and I think I've done it correctly, but it is not working

**i have created module and the code in config.xml**

```
<crontab>
        <jobs>
            <birthday_send>
                <schedule><cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>birthday/observer::sendBirthayEmail</model></run>
            </birthday_send>
        </jobs>
</crontab>
```

**Next is observer.php (in folder model) with method sendBirthayEmail**

```
class Test_Birthday_Model_Observer
{
    public function sendBirthayEmail()
    {
        //this collection get all users which have birthday on today
        $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->getCollection();
        $customer->addFieldToFilter('dob', array('like' => '%'.date("m").'-'.date("d").' 00:00:00'));
        $customer->addNameToSelect();
        $items = $customer->getItems();
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
        // send email or do something
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Could any 1 help me for running this  code 
i think everything is setup correctly .
i am testing it on localhost.
pls tell me if i am missing something.

Comment: You can enable the log & try putting something in Mage::log('I am here'); in the observer. As CRON  will not show the output directly. You can check it in system log

Comment: Did you configure a cronjob in your OS to call magentos cron.php or cron.sh?

Comment: @ simon no actually i just made the module and trying to run but it is not working 
@tejas ok i am trying this

Comment: Please put full config.xml

Comment: you need to call the cron script provided by magento : http://yourhost/magento_dir/cron.php than check into the table (cron_schedule) which maintains the cron jobs, check if birthday_send is listed in the table.